# is there a short way to do this?

Tags: c#

```
 public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
{
    if (input < 10)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    if (input > 10 && input < 20)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    if (input > 21 && input < 40)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    if (input > 41 && input < 70)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    if (input > 11 && input < 120)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    else
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the logic/difference in each of the cases? I can make out only minor differences... You should consider helping out those who are going to answer the question by providing necessary information, instead of letting them figure out the difference.

Comment: As your code is written you seem to miss the cases when input equals 10, 20, 21, etc. (use input >= 10 etc.) Yes, the if-elseif covers these cases (if input>11 and < 120; and else...) but the code looks as if they should be taken care of earlier. This may be intentional though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the common parts and try and extract them.

Your image tag of a "Full Star" never changes
Your image tag of an "Empty Star" never changes
so you can extract both of those for readability into variables.

Same goes for the formatter string, there will always be "5 consecutive star types"

How about

```
string fs = @"<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />"; //Full Star
string es = @"<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />"; //Empty Star

string format = @"{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}";

if(input < 10)
   return string.Empty;
else if(input < 20)
   return string.Format(format, fs, es, es, es, es);
else if(input < 40)
   return string.Format(format, fs, fs, es, es, es);
else if(input < 70)
   return string.Format(format, fs, fs, fs, es, es);
else if(input < 120)
   return string.Format(format, fs, fs, fs, fs, es);
else 
   return string.Format(format, fs, fs, fs, fs, fs);
```

Alternatively you could use a string builder

```
string fs = @"<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />"; //Full Star
string es = @"<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />"; //Empty Star

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fs);  
//No need for `sb.Append (input > 10 ? fs : es);` as we'll test "input < 10" in the return statement.
sb.Append (input > 20 ? fs : es);
sb.Append (input > 40 ? fs : es);
sb.Append (input > 70 ? fs : es);
sb.Append (input > 120 ? fs : es);

return (input < 10) ? string.Empty : sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I was going to answer this with a StringBuilder, but I much prefer your answer. +1 sir.

Comment: Still prefer StringBuilder, but this is pretty simple nonetheless.

Comment: I was in the middle of adding the stringbuilder solution... Personally I prefer the SB option, as it's shorter and personally I think a little cleaner but ternary operators aren't everyones cup of tea

Comment: @Eoin: Agreed. Though Thomas's/my solutions get around that with a bit of extra code.

Comment: I like the second one.  Ternary operators are definitely my cup of tea.

Answer (score 3):

That many string literals in code is bound to look horribly ugly. Also, I'm not sure why the gaps in the values are non-constant (or don't even increase regularly), but that's not a big issue.

Try this:

```
public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
{
    int numStars;

    if (input < 10)
        return string.Empty;
    else if (input < 20)
        numStars = 1;
    else if (input < 40)
        numStars = 2;
    else if (input < 70)
        numStars = 3;
    else if (input < 120)
        numStars = 4;
    else
        numStars = 5;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        sb.Append("<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />");
    for (int i = numStars; i < 5; i++)
        sb.Append("<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: no reason for not regular increase, i was just playing with numbers

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for posting a JavaScript solution (tested on Mozilla Rhino), but I don't know that much C# and I believe the algorithm is interesting here.

```
var rating = function(input) {
    var star  = '<img src="/images/star.png" alt="*" />',
        empty = '<img src="/images/star_empty.png" alt="*" />',
        steps = [10, 20, 40, 70, 120],
        max   = steps.length;

    for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
        if (input > steps[i]) {
            print(star);
        } else {
            print(empty);
        }
    }
};
```

Maybe it helps somehow.

Comment: A JavaScript really isn't too useful here, given that the "algorithm" itself is trivial, and it's the implementation that matters.

Comment: OK, maybe algorithm wasn't the right word. But the constructs used to have a solution are so basic that the language shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: It's not Ionut's fault the question is trivial.  His technique is useful and easy to adapt to C#.

Comment: @Ionut: I wasn't referring to your use of the word algorithm. My point was simply that the algorithm itself was trivial (I at least usually think of algorithms as slightly more complex things, though it's arguable). This is definitely a nice solution in JavaScript, I admit, but isn't too relevant here.

Comment: Ok, so it's easy enough to convert to C#. The main change would be to use a StringBuilder in place of the print statements.

Comment: I like this one and it is quite easy to transform into C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
{
    if (input < 10)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else if (input < 20)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    else if (input < 40)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    else if (input < 70)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    else if (input < 120)
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
    }
    else
    {
        return "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" /><img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />";
    }
}
```

Not much shorter really, but the readability is much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
{
    int nStars = 0;

    if (input < 10)
        return string.Empty;
    else if (input < 20)
        nStars = 1;
    else if (input < 40)
        nStars = 2;
    else if (input < 70)
        nStars = 3;
    else if (input < 120)
        nStars = 4;
    else
        nStars = 5;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < nStars; i++)
        sb.Append("<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />");
    for(int i = nStars; i < 5; i++)
        sb.Append("<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Almost identical to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying a loop such as (note the logic is off as I gave up on the solution):

```
public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
```

{
    String rating = "";

```
for(i=0;i<120;i+=10)
{
    if(input > i)
        rating += "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />";
    else
        rating += "<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
}

return rating;
```

}

But then noticed the non-linear growth in the ratings 10,20,40,70 etc...

Using the above answer you could shorten it and make it more readable by factoring out the strings to:

```
String star = "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />";
String emptyStar = "<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";
```

Which added to the answer above would make it:

```
if (input < 10)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else if (input < 20)
    {
        return star+emptyStar+emptyStar+emptyStar+emptyStar;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const string Star = "<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />";
const string Star_Empty = "<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"-\" />";

public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
{
    if (input < 10)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else if (input > 10 && input < 20)
    {
        return string.concat(Star, Star_Empty, Star_Empty, Star_Empty, Star_Empty);
    }
    else if (input > 21 && input < 40)
    {
        return string.concat(Star, Star, Star_Empty, Star_Empty, Star_Empty);
    }
    else if (input > 41 && input < 70)
    {
        return string.concat(Star, Star, Star, Star_Empty, Star_Empty);
    }
    else if (input > 11 && input < 120)
    {
        return string.concat(Star, Star, Star, Star, Star_Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        return string.concat(Star, Star, Star, Star, Star);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int starCount;
if (input < 10)
    return string.Empty;
else if (input < 20)
    starCount = 1;
else if (input < 40)
    starCount = 2
else if (input < 70)
    starCount = 3;
else if (input < 120)
    starCount = 4;
else
    starCount = 5;

StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
int i;
for(i = 0; i < starCount; i++)
    build.Append("<img src=\"/images/star.png\" alt=\"*\" />");
for(; i < 5; i++)
    build.Append("<img src=\"/images/star_empty.png\" alt=\"*\" />");

return build.ToString();
```

Still not great, but if you rationalize your input (so it doesn't jump by arbitrary amounts), you could get starCount from regular integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string RatingCalculator(int input)
    {
        if (input > 120)
        {
            return GetStart(5);
        }
        if (input > 70)
        {
            return GetStars(4);
        }
        if (input > 40)
        {
            return GetStars(3);
        }
        if (input > 20)
        {
            return GetStars(2);
        }
        if (input > 10)
        {
            return GetStars(1);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    //populate dictionary with values in your class ctor
    private static IDictionary<int, string> images=new Dictionary<int,string>();

    private static string GetStars(int stars)
    {
        if(images.ContainsKey(stars))
            return images[stars];
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (input < 10) return string.Empty;

    int noOfStars = input >= 120 ? 5 : Math.Min(input / 10, 4);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(
            string.Format("<img src=\"/images/{0}\" alt=\"*\" />",
                          i < noOfStars ? "star" : "starEmpty")
            );
    }

    return sb.ToString();
```